# Android home activity to different series of activities and then back to home activity?

Tags: android

I have different activities in my app having activity1(home), activity2, activity3 and so on and they are taking Jason parse data from one activity to another. When I go from activity1(home)--> activity2--> activity3--> and want to back to home activity after clicking home button it take's me to previous activity(activity2).

Here is my code:

```
  homeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            Intent home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    DashboardActivity.class);
            home.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(home);
        }
    });

    logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AlertDialogLogout();

        }
    });

    helpbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent helpActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    HelpActivity.class);
            startActivity(helpActivity);
        }
    });
    profilebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent viewProfile = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ViewProfileScreenAct.class);
            startActivity(viewProfile);
        }
    });

    socialbuttonIV.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            shareIt();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Show me how you call the Activity 2 from Activity 1 and after that Activity 3 from Activity 2. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use this on your home button click listener

```
 homeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
        Intent home = new Intent(youractivityname.this,
                yourhome_activityname.class);
        home.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(home);
    }
});
```

Comment: it's not working, still it take's to previous activity

Comment: clean and rebuild your project

Answer (score 0):

### Why don't you use simple intent to go back to first activity

```
  homeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DashboardActivity.class); 
            startActivity(home);
        } 
    });
```

Comment: using simple intent it takes the wrong Jason data to home activity and home activity sends same wrong data to another activity

Comment: @ Zohaib .... You can set flags to set the logic to act specifically when control is coming from the third activity

Comment: @ Devrath... i used flags like this home.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); but it didn't work. can you please suggest some thing else

Comment: @ Zohaib ....... I am not referring to intent flag..... Simple Boolean flag in first activity .... to act on a particular logic when that activity is started from last activity and to act differently in another condition

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of hopping from one activity to another in a circle, would be better (and easier) to have one activity, and change programmatically the layout shown to the user, by using a ViewPager, ViewFlipper and/or Fragments (depending on functionality)? This way, you don't have to change activities, remember their order (as you see its harder with activities), send data from one to another. All data will be stored in one place, and you just change/update the interface. By the way, in case the user wants to make changes to the entered data, he can go back and update it.